# Is there a way to prevent xaxis labels from overlapping in a flot.js bar graph?

Tags: javascript, flot

The space that I have allotted for the graph in my design is fairly small and if there are more than 5 categories in the graph the labels overlap each other.  Is there a way to prevent this?  Here is an example of what I'm running into: http://jsfiddle.net/bCYET/1/

```
var data = [
    ["Engineering",14],
    ["Communications",11],
    ["Business",9],
    ["Biology",5],
    ["Natural Sciences",2],
    ["Studio Art",2]
];

var options = {
    series: {
        bars: { 
            show: true,
            barWidth: .6,
            align: "center"
        }    
    },
       xaxis: {
           mode: "categories",
           tickLength: 0
       }
}

$.plot('#barchart', [data], options);
```

UPDATE: I figured out that I can put the legend in a container outside of the graph which will work for me.  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bCYET/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently an [open issue with flot.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/164). Of the solutions on that page, [flot-tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) is probably the easiest to use.

Comment: Thanks, I think I had tried that as well, but if the labels were long then the actual graph was squished to make space for the labels which didn't look great.  I figured out that I could specify a div container for the legend (so that it didn't cover up the graph), which will work for me.  I added that to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCYET/2/) for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

Now this issue has been fixed in v 0.8.3. Use this: http://www.flotcharts.org/blog/